# Nuxt3: use a plugin in a composable

Tags: plugins, vuejs3, nuxt3

In Nuxt3, I've created a plugin to use vuetify-use-dialog. The file is named vuetifyDialogPlugin.ts.

`import VuetifyUseDialog from "vuetify-use-dialog"; export default defineNuxtPlugin((nuxtApp) => { nuxtApp.vueApp.use(VuetifyUseDialog); });`

I want to create a composable where I use useSnackbar from this plugin.
In [the doc of Nuxt3](https://nuxt.com/docs/guide/directory-structure/composables), it's indicated that we can use plugin in composable with useNuxtApp. So, I've writen this code :

`export function useCustomSnackbar(text, color = "red", timeout = 5000) { return useNuxtApp().vuetifyDialogPlugin.useSnackbar({ text, snackbarProps: { timeout, color, location: "top", } }); }`

But an error occured : "TypeError: (intermediate value)().vuetifyDialogPlugin is undefined".

I've tried different names for the plugin, with and without $ in first character, but there is always the same error (undefined).

I've also tried the object syntax [indicated in the doc](https://nuxt.com/docs/guide/directory-structure/plugins#automatically-providing-helpers) but it did not work.

Please, does somebody know how to access my imported plugin in my composable?
Thanks.